# How do I know if I am calling numpy.array() or using built in array function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If, for example, I import as follows:

```
from numpy import empty, full, zeros, matrix, arange, asarray, array
```

Then I might have some list that I generated:

```
stuff = []

for i in range(N):
    stuff.append(things)
```

then, I realize I have to do some math! so I type:

```
math_stuff = array(stuff)
```

Since I didn't have to type numpy.array or np.array, based on how I declared my imports, how do I know that my IDE is preferring the numpy version over the built in version? Is this automatic?

I checked the docs on for numpy.array() and python's built in array(), and it looks like they both accept the same "list like" argument.

Comment: `print(type(math_stuff))`... But you are using numpy array, since you've imported it from numpy. If you've also imported a module/function/class/object earlier with a same name from another library. The last import will override others.

Comment: @umutto Ok, so the last import will override earlier imports and any built in functions of the same name. Got it.

Comment: @rocksNwaves: There is no built-in `array` name in Python. You can `import` the `array` module, but if you do that, you're explicitly creating the conflict (which is won by whoever took the name last). The code you provide doesn't show any indication that you did `import array` or `from array import array`, so the answer is there is no conflict, because there is only one thing named `array` in the code shown.

Comment: Not only that but last thing that you've defined will override earlier stuffs. If you were to define `array = 'hello world'`, now the array keyword would represent the string hello world. It is the same for imports and modules etc..

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ok, I saw the array class in the python documentation, so I thought it was something I could just use any time. I didn't realize I'd have to import it as well.

Comment: By the way, the idiomatic way of importing numpy is `import numpy as np`, rather than `from numpy import stuff`. That way you can write `np,array`, `np.empty`, etc., which is a pretty good balance—a lot more concise than `numpy.empty`, but no risk of colliding with other things named `empty`.

Comment: @rocksNwaves: Yar. The only names that exist without you `import`ing them from somewhere are [the built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs) and [built-in constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#built-in-consts). Aside from those specific things, everything else comes from imports.

Comment: One more thing: if you're at the interactive interpreter, it can be hard to remember what you imported, defined, whatever before lunch. But if you get confused, you can type `help(array)`, or `repr(array)`, or `type(array)`, and usually any of those is enough to remind you what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters have said, you can easily tell which one is being used just by looking at the most recent import statement. However, in case you get worried/confused, you can also directly check the module from which a function or class originates using Python's handy built-in reflection features.

For example, the following Python statement:

```
print(array.__module__)
```

will print out the string `'numpy.core.multiarray'` if `array` was imported from the `numpy` package, or the string `'array'` if it was imported from the `array` package.

#### If `x.__module__` fails, explore alternatives via `dir(x)`

@ShadowRanger raises the good point that some Python objects don't have the `__module__` property. In particular, if you run just `import array`, then `array` is a module and the `print(array.__module__)` call will fail. In these kinds of situations you can always discover what reflection information is actually available via the `dir()` function.

`dir()` is easily my favorite feature of Python. For any Python object `x`, `dir(x)` prints out the complete list of the attributes of `x`. For example, given that you just ran `import array`, executing `dir(array)` would then print out:

```
['ArrayType',
'__doc__',
'__file__',
'__loader__',
'__name__',
'__package__',
'__spec__',
'_array_reconstructor',
'array',
'typecodes']
```

Which shows that even though the array module lacks `__module__`, if does have other reflection information available such as `__name__` and `__file__`.

Comment: Although if you just did `import array`, rather than `from array import array`, `print(array.__module__)` will raise an `AttributeError`, since `__module__` is not defined on modules themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to keep your namespaces clean, if you can:

do: `import numpy` or `import numpy as np`,

instead of: `from numpy import empty, full, zeros, matrix, arange, asarray, array`

In case it is not up to you, and it is unclear what came earlier, `help(array)`, or `repr(array)`, or `type(array)` will be handy. (as mentioned in the comments)